# Sending email with submitted form data

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a form in my website, if the user fill it out and send it then I receive confirmation e-mail with his data. I know how to do it via PHP but I have to use only ASP and I'm not familiar with ASP. Thanks for your advice and help. So my form looks like this:

```
                  <tr>
                    <td>*First Name: </td>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="FirstName" required  id="field"/></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>*Last Name: </td>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="LastName" required id="field" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>Company: </td>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Company" id="field" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>*Address: </td>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Address" required id="field" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">*City: </td>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="City" required id="field" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">*State: </td>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="State" required id="field" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">*Zip Code: </td>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="ZipCode" required id="field" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">*Phone: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastname" required id="field" /></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ext. </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Extension" id="field-extensions"/></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">Fax: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Fax" id="field" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">*Email: </td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="Email" required id="field" /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" align="left"><br /><br />Comments:<br />
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="120" id="field-comments" name="Comments"> </textarea><br />                      
                    <button type="submit" id="sub-button">Submit</button></td>                       
                  </tr>

                </table>

           </form>
```

Comment: There are tons of examples with that one - just search for "contact form on asp"

Comment: You should fix the formatting in your code so its a little easier to read

Answer (score 2):

assuming that your using Post method in ur Form : in the target (action page)

do the Following

```
<%
Dim name, lastName, Company, Address, City
name = Request.Form("FirstName")
lastName= Request.Form("LastName")
Company= Request.Form("Company")
Address= Request.Form("Address")
City= Request.Form("City")
.....


Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="user Iformation"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="yourselef@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="user information "& name & "lastName: " & lastName & .....(rest of params)
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing

%>
```

regards

Comment: King A Majid thanks for your answer. I tried to copy your code and save it as form.aspx and in the < form action="form.action" method="post"> but i wasn't able to get the expected result because something is wrong with the web.conf File (<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>)

Comment: @MoudiMunich you tagged your question as **classic ASP** so this answer give you code in that language. In the future pay more attention to tagging properly please.

Comment: @shadow wizard I don't know the difference between ASP.NET and ASP Classic because I worked only with PHP. So if you want to be helpful look at my code and tell me what's the solution.